# Incorrect Image Dimensions using pillow/PIL

Tags: python-3.x, image, anaconda, python-imaging-library

In Anaconda, I am using the PIL library to import a Nikon NEF image and display its size. The original image dimensions (according to the original image file) are 4608 pixels by 3072 pixels, but when I run my program the dimensions are said to be 160 by 120 pixels. How do I get the correct image size? Code displayed below:

```
    from PIL import Image
    import numpy as np

    im = Image.open('DSC_0016.NEF')
    width, height = im.size
    print(width,height)
```

Comment: There's a small 160x120 JPEG Preview image at the start, I believe... https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=30454 Try `im.seek(2)` or similar

Comment: I can't get the above to work, but maybe try `rawpy`... https://pypi.org/project/rawpy/  If you are really stuck, you may need `ufraw` or `dcraw`.

Comment: I tried rawpy and got close to the right image size, it seemed to add a few pixels, but it was better. However, I tried changing the file to .jpg and the code above gave me the right image size. Thanks for your help!